# Jquery OnFinished Start over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

i'm using [jquery steps](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps) to make  wizard i'm not sure how to start over steps after getting in to final step.

```
$("#etup-wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slide",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical",
    onInit: (event, currentIndex) => {
        initSetupTableGrid();
        $('#addsetup').on('click', onClickSetupTableModal);
    },
    onStepChanging: (event, currentIndex, newIndex) => {
        var valid = $('form#layoutConfig').valid();
        return valid;
    },
    onFinishing: (event, currentIndex) => {
        return true;
    },
    onFinished: (event, currentIndex) => {
        // after submit form need to start first step again
    }
});
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: how about destroying and rebuilding?

Comment: how to destroy? you mean make it null ?

Comment: They have methods to destroy. Please refer the methods section in thr documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy.

Just add `$("#wizard-t-0").get(0).click();` in onFinished.

Enjoy.